# Pull a list of names assigned to a specified trainer in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to pull a list of people assigned to a particular trainer. In column A I have the trainer name, In column B the Last Name, In Column C the First name. I'd like a list in a different column which sorts the names under the name of their trainer. I've attached a picture of what I'd like. I typed in the information manually, so don't be fooled into thinking that I've already got what I want. I'm thinking that I might need to use Vlookup, but I'm not sure that's right or exactly how to do it in this case.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the array formula to go into cell N2:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1[[#All],[Full Name]],SMALL(IF(Table1[[#All],[Trainer]]=N$1,ROW(Table1[[#All],[Trainer]])),ROW()-1)),"")
```

For this to work, you need to:

1. First turn your data into a table. Click any cell in your data then click on Insert > Table.
2. Copy the formula, then double click into cell N2, paste the formula and instead of pressing just Enter to save the formula, you need to press `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`. If saved correctly the formula will appear with {Curly Braces} in the formula
3. Fill the formula down enough rows to include all trainees. Then fill the formula across the columns for the other trainers.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. That was in my working spreadsheet. It should go into N2 - the first cell where you want the result.

Comment: Great! That worked a treat! Now just to learn to make those myself.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done a few ways:

1. Repeated applications of the Advanced Filter that saves the results to different locations. This is tedious to update.
2. Write VBA. This takes a while to learn.
3. Use an array formula. This is complicated to understand.
4. Use a Pivot Table. Doesn't give the exact layout you want, but is very simple to create and to update.

I'd suggest trying the Pivot Table using following steps:

1. Click on a cell in your data.
2. Insert > Table (using a table means the Pivot Table with automatically include all new lines added to your data)
3. Insert > Pivot Table and click OK
4. Add Trainer to Row Labels
5. Then Add Full Name to Row Labels
6. You can adjust layout if you want from the Pivot Table Tools > Design tab. I prefer changing Report Layout to "Show in Tabular Form" and changing Subtotals to "Do Not Show Subtotals"
7. After adding new rows to your table, right click on the Pivot Table and select Refresh.

[image: Img]